# Radix sort function won't work for base 2?

Tags: c++, radix-sort

I am writing a program that takes an array of integers and sorts them for bases 16 8 10 and 2. My function works for all bases except 2. Its not sorting the numbers correctly. I have been looking around and no place particularly explains the problem. I think im supposed to use shift (>> <<) but I dont know exactly how?

```
void Sortfunc(int myarray[], int n, int base){

queue<int> bins[10]; 
int MAX=4; // max digits 
int COUNTER=0;// position of counter

while (COUNTER < MAX) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){// sorts array by digit 
        int dividor=pow(base,COUNTER);
        int temp = myarray[i]; 
        int value = static_cast<int>((temp/dividor)%10); //gets the decimal  
        bins[value].push(temp); 
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing your code I don't think we can give you much advice. Can you post what you have and the specific error you're getting?

Comment: The error im getting is that the array isn't being sorted correctly when I input base 2. works fine for all other bases.

Comment: is there any reason you wouldn't use `std::sort`?

Comment: I have to create a function that uses radixsort

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you've still hard-coded the fact that you're working in base ten into your implementation in two spots:

```
queue<int> bins[10]; // <--- Here
int MAX=4;
int COUNTER=0;

while (COUNTER < MAX) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int dividor=pow(base,COUNTER);
        int temp = myarray[i]; 
        int value = static_cast<int>((temp/dividor)%10); // <--- Here
        bins[value].push(temp); 
    }
```

This means that even if you try changing the base, you won't necessarily be sorting using the base that the user has provided.

Additionally, I would recommend not using `pow` here to compute powers. Floating-point computations are inherently imprecise and for cases like these where you cannot afford any margin of error, you're better off using integral values all the way through your calculations.